# If I cancel my Onedrive subscription, will the local files remain intact?

Tags: onedrive

I have set up  an account (which offers unlimited storage and stores different versions) with company XYZ. This backsup the Onedrive folder to the XYZ cloud

When I cancel my Onedrive subscription, I believe that all the local files should remain intact.. is that the case?

Comment: It will provided the files also exist as local files

Comment: If you are worried, then copy them off to other media first. That way, even if something goes wrong, you won't lose anything.

Answer (score 1):

Your local files will remain intact. Make sure to uninstall OneDrive so an accidental deletion in the cloud does not delete your local files.